# error with lcc compiler

Tags: c

I am trying to compile the following program in windows but I get an error which I do not understand. I have added the correct libraries and header files, yet I get this error. I am using this lcc win32 compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "stack.h"

int main()
{
    stackADT operandStack;
    operandStack = NewStack();

    return 0;
}

stack.obj .text: undefined reference to '_GetBlock'
stack.obj .text: undefined reference to '_FreeBlock'
stack.obj .text: undefined reference to '_Error'
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Comment: What is your build command? Do you have a stack.c or a genlib.c perhaps? Please add these details in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not compiler errors but linker errors. You need to link your program with the library or obj files that contain `GetBlock()` etc.